# How do you test for values created in a new Buffer in unit tests

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, sinon

Let's say we have some code that does this:

```
callFunction(new Buffer(foo));
```

And we want to unit test this call with a sinon.js spy:

```
var spy = sinon.spy(callFunction);
expect(spy.to.have.been.calledWith(foo));
```

This will fail because `callFunction` was called with `new Buffer(foo)` and not `foo`. The tests pass if we do `expect(spy.to.have.been.calledWith(new Buffer(foo))` but is it wise to keep creating new buffers for every test? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Are you sure `expect(spy.to.have.been.calledWith(new Buffer(foo))` passes? Because I think it shouldn't...considering you're passing in a different buffer.

What I'd do is that I would create a custom sinon matcher (http://sinonjs.org/docs/#sinon-match-custom).

Comment: I was surprised too, but it did work on my computer, but then had issues on other machines for some reason. Can you provide an example of how you would do this with a sinon matcher? The documentation you linked is a bit sparse. I'll be happy to choose your answer as the Accepted Answer if you leave one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So how about something like this (in CoffeeScript):

```
bufferEqual = (expectation) -> 
  sinon.match.instanceOf(Buffer)
  .and(sinon.match (val) -> val.toString() == expectation)
```

or JS version:

```
function bufferEqual(expectation) {
  return sinon.match.instanceOf(Buffer).and(sinon.match(function(val) {
    return val.toString() === expectation;
  }));
};
```

Comment: Can you provide sample in JavaScript?